# How to share steps between jobs

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have `azure-pipelines.yml` file with 4 jobs, `Format_Checking`, `Unit_Tests`, `Cypress_Tests`, and `Build`

These steps are common between all of them:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1
  persistCredentials: true

# Set Azure Devops CLI default settings
- bash: az devops configure --defaults organization=$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) project=$(System.TeamProject)
  displayName: 'Set default Azure DevOps organization and project'

# Get last successfully commit infos from Azure Devops
- bash: |
    LAST_SHA=$(az pipelines build list --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) --definition-ids $(System.DefinitionId) --result succeeded --top 1 --query "[0].triggerInfo.\"ci.sourceSha\"")
    echo "Last successful commit SHA: $LAST_SHA"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_SHA]$LAST_SHA"
  displayName: 'Get last successful commit SHA'
  condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

# Required for nx affected if we're on a branch
- script: git fetch origin develop --depth 1
  displayName: 'fetch develop branch'

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '20.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    corepack enable
    yarn install --immutable
  displayName: 'install dependencies'
```

and whenever I want to modify something, I have to go and modify all of them.

1. Is there any way to reuse the same steps between the jobs?
2. Can I actually make the jobs start from the same point, to avoid installing `node_modules` multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to reuse the same steps between the jobs?

Yes. We can define the tasks in the [YAML template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes).

Then we can reuse the same steps between the jobs.

For example:

**template.yml:**

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1
  persistCredentials: true

# Set Azure Devops CLI default settings
- bash: az devops configure --defaults organization=$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) project=$(System.TeamProject)
  displayName: 'Set default Azure DevOps organization and project'

# Get last successfully commit infos from Azure Devops
- bash: |
    LAST_SHA=$(az pipelines build list --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) --definition-ids $(System.DefinitionId) --result succeeded --top 1 --query "[0].triggerInfo.\"ci.sourceSha\"")
    echo "Last successful commit SHA: $LAST_SHA"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BASE_SHA]$LAST_SHA"
  displayName: 'Get last successful commit SHA'
  condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

# Required for nx affected if we're on a branch
- script: git fetch origin develop --depth 1
  displayName: 'fetch develop branch'

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '20.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    corepack enable
    yarn install --immutable
  displayName: 'install dependencies'
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
jobs:
- job: Format_Checking
  steps:
  - template: template.yml
  

- job: Unit_Tests
  steps:
  - template: template.yml

- job: Cypress_Tests
  steps:
  - template: template.yml
```

> Can I actually make the jobs start from the same point, to avoid installing node_modules multiple times?

Each job is independent. I'm afraid we are not able to make the jobs start from the same point.

But to reduce the time of installing node_modules, we can use the [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops).

It can cache the node_modules folder and reuse the packages in the pipeline cache. It will reduce the time of the installing node_modules.

Or you can use self-hosted agent and let the jobs running on the same agent. Then they can share the node_modules folder between jobs.